# ExpressJS returns 500 code all the time when trying to send some data

Tags: api, express, backend

I'm actually working on an API using web-scrapping, but I have a problem that I can't understand.

I have the following route for a GET request:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const currency = req.params.id;
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/${currency}/`
    );
    const html = res.data;
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const price = $(".statsValue").first().text();
    const data = {
      market: Number(price.slice(1).replaceAll(",", "")),
    };
    console.log(data);
    res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I make a request for this route, I just get the 500 status code, even knowing it has the data.
When I call the API route, it logs this on the console:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server is running on port 5000
{ market: 454939957399 }
```

This means that it has the data, logs the data, and on the `res.status(200).json(data)` something fails.

I have the exact 2 lines of status and json response in another API call and it works perfectly, but I've been like 2 hours with this one for almost nothing.

I hope someone can help me <3

Comment: so…what's the actual error saying…?

Comment: I just get a 500 code, it skips the last line (res.status(200).json(data)) even having the right data

Comment: You realise that it's your own code that's returning the 500 code, right?

Comment: I know i have the error 500 in case of an error, but it's not throwing any error, it just stops working on the last line of the try, without any reason.

Comment: So the `catch (error)` block in your code isn't being called? And Express is also not logging anything?

Comment: It's being called and returning an empty object on the request. But the res.status(200).json(data) shoud be called, as the data object is being logged and not empty.

Comment: So if it's being called, why don't you `console.log(error)` before returning a 500 code? It will make things a whole lot more clear…

Comment: TypeError: res.status is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the `res` argument by a new variable:

```
const res = await axios.get(…);
```